# how to get the result of second select statement in mysql using python?

Tags: python, mysql, database

I am using python to make a connection with the mySql database and run a procedure. In the procedure, there are two select statements that return the result.
I am using the following code to execute procedure

```
query = "Call procedure_name()"
cursor.execute(query)
procedureResult = cursor.fetchall();
```

but this returns the only result of the first select statement.
How can I get the result of second select?

procedure

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `my_database`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `dim_get_orders`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `dim_get_orders`()
 BEGIN
SELECT 'hi';

SELECT 'hello';
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Show us your procedure (or an example of it)

Comment: @Sir_FZ edited my question with procedure

Comment: You're getting the result of the second select?

Comment: This seems like what you need to fix in your procedure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317971/mysql-stored-procedure-with-multiple-select-statements-from-different-tables

Comment: but in my case first select may have multiple records/rows

Answer (score -1):

Read the "DB API 2.0 Specifications" on cursor objects. According to it, a stored procedure call can have a `nextset()` method to get a second query.

I have not used `cur.nextset()` on a MySQL server. But it works.