# INSERT INTO with SELECT .... what if SELECT returns 0 rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a stored procedure with the following code:

```
INSERT INTO vt_benutzer_medien_liste (`BenutzerID`, `ReportID`, `MedienDateiTypID`, `Dateiname`, `Dateidatum`, `Dateigroesse`, `Bemerkungen`)
SELECT UserID, ReportID, COALESCE(vtmd.ID,16), Filename, FileDate, FileSize, Message 
FROM vt_medien_dateityp AS vtmd 
WHERE vtmd.Dateiendung = SUBSTRING_INDEX(Filename,'.',-1)
LIMIT 1
```

UserID, ReportID, Filename, FileDate, FileSize and Message are Parameters

The Insert part is working fine. The fileextension supplied in the parameter "Filename" is compared with a list of fileextensions in the table vtmd.
This also is working fine, as long as the fileextension exists in vtmd.

If not, it should get a default value of 16 -> COALESCE(vtmd.ID,16)
But this doesnt happen. The procedure finishes without any errors and no inserts has been made because the SELECT finds/returns no row.

What could I do?

PS: The alias is there for readability.

UPDATE

The SELECT return an empty result. This is the case where I want to return 16 as a default value.

Comment: Run just select statement and you will see if it returns data

Comment: Have you tried to just run the `SELECT` without `INSERT`?  I'm pretty sure it returns nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
BEGIN
SELECT @XDateiTypID := COALESCE((SELECT ID FROM vt_medien_dateityp WHERE Dateiendung = SUBSTRING_INDEX(Filename,'.',-1) LIMIT 1),16);
INSERT INTO vt_benutzer_medien_liste (`BenutzerID`, `ReportID`, `MedienDateiTypID`, `Dateiname`, `Dateidatum`, `Dateigroesse`, `Bemerkungen`)
VALUES (UserID, ReportID, @XDateiTypID, Filename, FileDate, FileSize, Message);
END
```

1. Handle the SELECT as a variable (**@XDateiTypID** in my case).
2. If the variable stays *NULL*, it will get overwritten by using COALESCE with the default value (16 in my case).
3. After that, just use the variable in the VALUES section and you're done.

PS: [BEGIN .. END needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317971/mysql-stored-procedure-with-multiple-select-statements-from-different-tables) as it is a stored procedure.

Answer (score 2):

If your SELECT returns no rows then nothing to INSERT. Having COALESCE won't force an INSERT as the SELECT has no rows, even if you specified a COALESCE for all the columns, this won't insert anything if no rows are returned from your SELECT .

There is a difference between null value in a returned row and no row at all.